# One mac to create 2 certificates

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Is it possible to **create** more then one ios distribution certificate on one mac machine?

When I double click the certificate it does not create the key in my keychain until.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for a new one, however that is not the equivalent of creating two. I dont believe you can create two on one machine as it is a distinct secret pair from your computer to their service. What you can do though if you need to export your development certificate to another computer is export from XCode a provisioning profile and install that on the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate doesn't create the key, you do.  When you perform the first step in Keychain Access when you request a certificate from a certificate authority, this generates the key and gives you a file Apple can use to sign it.  When you install the certificate, it merely gets attached to the key that was there already.

In order to have more than one distribution certificate, you will have to create two keys and ask Apple to sign each one.  You will then receive a certificate for each one.  However I don't believe under normal circumstances Apple will sign more than one key.